# hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files in same directory not working

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, import

I am trying to run sql scripts on startup of the webapp using hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files, but this doesn't seem to be working. I am using the following in my persistence.properties:

```
dataSource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
dataSource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/rays_rentals?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
dataSource.username=root
dataSource.password=

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create

hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files=bikes.sql
```

My bikes.sql file is saved in the same place as my properties file.
Here is my sql file:

```
INSERT INTO `bikes` (`id`, `brand`, `model`) VALUES (1, 'Giant', 'Propel Advanced 0');
```

Here is my Bike model:

```
package com.BrightFuture.RaysRentalSystem.bikes;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Proxy;

@Entity
@Proxy(lazy = false)
@Table(name = "bikes")
public class Bike {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="bike", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<BikeRecord> bikeRecords = new ArrayList<BikeRecord>();

@Column(name="brand", nullable=false)
private String brand;

@Column(name="model", nullable=false)
private String model;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain what you mean when saying _doesn't seem to be working_? And do you really use `persistance.properties` - or `persistence.properties`?

Comment: I check my database and the values I am trying to insert are not there. And i use persistence.properties. sorry about that.. updated my question

Comment: @Shaun Lavelle have you checked your logs, no exceptions.

Comment: I Get no exceptions. Also do i need to configure hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files so i can use it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. everything in my question is right.. i was just missing the configuration for it in my JpaConfig

Answer (score -2):

Please modify your properties file with below attribute:
`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update`

Comment: This is what I thought. create and create-drop only.